# How many applications should be defined in Azure B2C for a micro-service based infrastructure?

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, azure-ad-b2c

In the preview for Azure AD B2C you can define applications. Each application is then given a name, a client ID, app key and a few settings to define whether to include web app / web api and whether to allow implicit flow. In the 'old' world of Azure AD you had much greater control as to the interaction between applications such as "this application can access graph api", or "this application can talk to this service" whereas in the new world order this doesn't appear possible (at least from a portal UI perspective). My question is: given the lack of apparent control in Azure AD B2C for an infrastructure that has a growing number of microservices, does it make sense to create an 'application' per service in Azure AD B2C (and indeed per environment)? Or should the whole system share the same application (and therefore client id?).

Answer (score 0):

(I would like to comment on that but my current score does not allow me to do that)

What we do: we have Client Ids for each Web and API App (container for micro services). When initializing authentication for the API Apps we put all Client Ids which are allowed to talk to the API in the `ValidAudiences`:

```
    public static string clientIds = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidClientIds"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // This is where you specify that your API accepts tokens only from its own clients
            ValidAudiences = clientIds.Split(',')
        };

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata and signing keys from the OpenID Connect metadata endpoint
            AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, Globals.ODICEndpointVersion, Globals.OIDCMetadataSuffix, commonPolicy)))
        });
    }
```